# ASP.NET server tags rendered in client HTML, not values?

Tags: asp.net, html, controls, server-tags

Maybe I've forgotten how to use these, but I am going crazy trying to inject a server-side value into an HTML output.  There are reasons why I am doing this inline, and not server-side, so please don't suggest that as a solution.

This code on the server side:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>' />;
```

Renders as this in the client HTML sent to the browser:

```
<span id="Label1"> <%= DateTime.Now.ToString()></span>;
```

And it displays as big fat empty space, and nothing output to the interface.

If I change the ASP source to using the "#" character to define as data-binding syntax, then the rendered output to browser becomes:

```
<span id="Label1"></span>
```

### EDIT:

Setting Label text was just a simplified object for the sake of asking the question.  In real life, I am setting the CssClass attribute, which does not allow me to use the "wrapping" workaround some have suggested.  I wanted to set a public property and have all the controls update from it dynamically on page load.

Ideally, since I already have all the controls laid out on the aspx page. Just looking to add an attribute. I wanted to have:

```
<asp:textbox ID='MyTxtBox1' CssClass='<% strVal1 %>' />  
<asp:textbox ID='MyTxtBox2' CssClass='<% strVal1 %>' />  
<asp:textbox ID='MyTxtBox3' CssClass='<% strOtherVal %>' />  
<asp:textbox ID='MyTxtBox4' CssClass='<% strVal1 %>' />
```

Now what it looks like I need to do is repeat all my (250+) controls on the codebehind in a block of code that looks like:

```
MyTxtBox1.CssClass=strVal1  
MyTxtBox2.CssClass=strVal1  
MyTxtBox4.CssClass=strVal1  

MyTxtBox3.CssClass=strOtherVal
```

Comment: **Try this**
`<span id="Label1"> <%=DateTime.Now.ToString()%></span>;`
**Instead of:**
`<span id="Label1"> <%=DateTime.Now.ToString()></span>;`

Comment: Label was just a simplified version for the sake of asking the question.  Please see the other comments below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that may not work on a compiled Web Application as it's not interpreted at run-time like a C# "Web Site".  However, I was able to get it to work wrapping the label around the value:

```cs
<asp:Label runat="server"><%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Ok, well that works for my simplified version, but only somewhat based on the ability to wrap the code around the text of a label.  In the real life scenario, I need to dynamically inject a value into the CssClass attribute of a server tag which does not have that same wrapping workaround.  It seems that my issues is that I am trying to use these dynamic attributes wit a "<asp:" server control.  If I adjust the a simple HTML object (such as "<input type='text'... />"), it works without issue.

Comment: Ideally, since I already have all the controls laid out on the aspx page. Just looking to add an attribute. I wanted to have:  
    <asp:textbox ID=MyTxtBox1 CssClass='<% strVal1 %'>
    <asp:textbox ID=MyTxtBox2 CssClass='<% strVal1 %'>
    <asp:textbox ID=MyTxtBox3 CssClass='<% strOtherVal %'>
    <asp:textbox ID=MyTxtBox4 CssClass='<% strVal1 %'>


Now what it looks like I need to do is repeat all my controls on the codebehind in a block of code that looks like  
    MyTxtBox1.CssClass=strVal1
    MyTxtBox2.CssClass=strVal
    MyTxtBox4.CssClass=strVal
  
    MyTxtBox3.CssClass=strOtherVal

Answer (score 0):

Set the Label1.Text = value instead of trying to use server side attrs inside of the server control

Comment: The Attribute I am workin with in real life is CssClass.  I wanted to set a public property and have all the controls update from it on page load.

Since I already have all the controls laid out on the aspx page. Just looking to add an attribute. I wanted to have:  
    <asp:textbox ID=MyTxtBox1 CssClass='<% strVal1 %'>
    <asp:textbox ID=MyTxtBox2 CssClass='<% strOtherVal %'>

Now what it looks like I need to do is repeat all my (250) controls on the codebehind in a block of code that looks like  
    MyTxtBox1.CssClass=strVal1
    MyTxtBox2.CssClass=strOtherVal